# I created a DSL to define factories in ruby. Is there a better way to do it?

Tags: ruby, metaprogramming

I have ruby application and I want to implement a DSL to define Factories. Factories are classes that instantiates some object, execute some logic in the process, perform some validations and execute some callbacks depending on the results (succeeded or failed):

```
f = Factory.new

f.create(foo: :bar) do |on|
  on.success { puts 'hey from success action callback' }
  on.failure { puts 'hey from failure action callback' }
end
```

Ok, this is not that hard to do, but I also want to stop the create method right after the method fails or succeeds, something like:

```
def create(options = {})
  # some logic
  failed! # this method stops execution and yields the callback object
  puts "you'll never see this"
end
```

What I came up with is this: https://gist.github.com/esdras/631a04769f24856c6d7f

See a partial version below:

```
require 'fiber'

class Factory

  class Callbacks
    # omitted some code here, this class is basically a container for 
    # success and failure callbacks
  end

  def failed!
    @callbacks.failed!
    resume_context
  end

  def succeeded!
    @callbacks.succeeded!
    resume_context
  end

  def resume_context ; Fiber.yield ; end

  def self.handle(name, &method_body)
    define_method "__original_#{name}__", &method_body

    define_method name do |*args, &block|
      @callbacks = Callbacks.new(self, block)
      Fiber.new { send("__original_#{name}__", *args) }.resume
      @callbacks
    end
  end

  handle :create do |options = {}|
    puts options.inspect
    puts "in create"
    succeeded!
    puts 'after succeeded, never reached here'
  end

end
```

As you can see the class method `handle` defines two methods: `__original_create__` and `create` which wraps `__original_create__` in a `Fiber` to make it possible to stop execution immediately and execute the callbacks. My question is: Is there a better way to do this? Without creating that `__original_create__` method or even without using Fibers?

I already tried this:

```
  def self.handle(name, &method_body)
    define_method name do |*args, &block|
      @callbacks = Callbacks.new(self, block)
      Fiber.new { method_body.call *args }.resume 
      # above method_body is evaluated in the context of the class.
      @callbacks
    end
  end
```

but `method_body` is evaluated in the context of the class, not the instance:

I also tried to instance_eval the `method_body` like this:

```
  def self.handle(name, &method_body)
    define_method name do |*args, &block|
      @callbacks = Callbacks.new(self, block)
      Fiber.new { instance_eval &method_body }.resume 
      # above we lost the parameters defined by the handle method
      @callbacks
    end
  end
```

but I lost the reference to the parameters defined by:

```
handle :create do |param1, param2|
  # method body
end
```

The only way I found is defining a method with the block passed to the `handle` method and after defining a wrapper method that calls the original method, like I did above with `__original_create__`. I'm not ok with defining an extra method, there got to be another way to do this. :(

Any insights would be appreciated.

Comment: won't `method_body.call(*args)` work?

Comment: @UriAgassi Thank you form commenting, but no, method_body is evaluated in the context of the class not the instance. I updated my question and posted a link to a gist with a complete version of my code.

Comment: Why do you use Fibers at all? Try `instance_exec *args, &method_exec`

Comment: That did it `instance_exec *args, &method_body` is exactly what I needed to get rid of that extra method. I use Fibers to control the flow. I want the method to stop, yield the callbacks and return with only one method call, like: `failed!`. I don't want to do `yield @callbacks and return`. Thank you very much.

Comment: @UriAgassi I'm happy with your solution, I didn't know about `instance_exec`. I don't have a problem with Fibers but if you have a better way to accomplish the same thing, I'd appreciate your suggestions. Could you write an answer so I can accept, please? And thank you again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what you need the `Fiber` for, so I will leave it, but you need is [`instance_exec`](http://apidock.com/ruby/BasicObject/instance_exec)

```
def self.handle(name, &method_body)
  define_method name do |*args, &block|
    @callbacks = Callbacks.new(self, block)
    Fiber.new { instance_exec *args, &method_body }.resume 
    # above we lost the parameters defined by the handle method
    @callbacks
  end
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that is exactly what I needed. If anyone is interested, I use `Fiber` to stop execution, yield the callbacks immediately and ignore everything below the `failed!` method. Not sure if there is a way to accomplish this in only one method call without `Fiber`. Without `Fiber` I must do this: `failed! and return`. I think that the `Fiber` thing should be in another question though...

Answer (score 0):

One way to do it is to use `throw` and `catch`.

```
def create(options = {})
  case catch(:result) do
    throw :result, :success if ...
    throw :result, :error if ...
  end
  when :success then ...
  when :error then ...
  end
end
```

Comment: Thank you @sawa for answering, I'm not sure if I follow what you are suggesting. I want to follow the principle "Tell don't ask" in the create method. That's why I want the `failed!` and `succeeded` methods to stop execution immediately and yield the callback object.